# Pandas/Pythonic way to groupby a column X, within each group, return value in column Y based on value in column Z

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

Reproducible example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, '2015-12-15', 10],
                   [1, '2015-12-16', 13], 
                   [1, '2015-12-17', 16], 
                   [2, '2015-12-15', 19],
                   [2, '2015-12-11', 22], 
                   [2, '2015-12-18', 25],
                   [3, '2015-12-14', 28], 
                   [3, '2015-12-12', 31], 
                   [3, '2015-12-15', 34]])

df.columns = ['X', 'Y', 'Z']
print(df.dtypes)
print()
print(df)
```

The output of reproducible example and the datatype of each column:

```
X     int64
Y    object
Z     int64
dtype: object

   X           Y   Z
0  1  2015-12-15  10
1  1  2015-12-16  13
2  1  2015-12-17  16
3  2  2015-12-15  19
4  2  2015-12-11  22
5  2  2015-12-18  25
6  3  2015-12-14  28
7  3  2015-12-12  31
8  3  2015-12-15  34
```

Expected Output:

```
   X           Y   Z
0  1  2015-12-15  10
1  1  2015-12-15  10
2  2  2015-12-11  22
3  2  2015-12-15  19
4  3  2015-12-12  31
5  3  2015-12-15  34
```

Explanation of what that output is:

For every group in column `X` after grouping by `X`, I want one row with the value in column `Z`
where value in column `Y` for that group is the `min(all dates/object in column Y)` and for the same
group, another row with the value in column 'Z' where value in column `Y` for that group is the `some custom date that definitely exists for all groups which will be hardcoded`. So every group would have two rows.

In my output, For group `1`, value in column `Z` is `10`, because the value in column `Z` associated with
the minimum of all dates in column `Y` for group `1`, `12-15-2015` is `10`. For the same group `1`, the second row for this group `1`, the value in column `Z` for the custom date `12-15-2015` is also `10`. For group `2`, `min(all dates/objects in column Y)` is `2015-12-11`, the corresponding value in column `Z` for group `2` with value in column `Y`, `2015-12-11` is `22`. And the for the custom date `12-15-2015`, it is `19`.

Here is what I'm assuming to be some linear time search/retarded code that I wrote to accomplish this:

```
uniqueXs = list(dict(Counter(df['X'].tolist())).keys()) #Get every unique item in column X is a list. 
df_list = [] #Empty list that will have rows of my final DataFrame

for x in uniqueXs: #Iterate through each unique value in column X

    idfiltered_dataframe = df.loc[df['X'] == x] #Filter DataFrame based on the current value in column X 
                                                #(iterating through list of all values)

    min_date = min(idfiltered_dataframe['Y']) #Min of column Y
    custom_date = '2015-12-15' #Every group WILL have this custom date.

    mindatefiltered_dataframe = idfiltered_dataframe.loc[idfiltered_dataframe['Y'] == min_date] #Within group, filter rows where column Y has minimum date
    customdatefiltered_dataframe = idfiltered_dataframe.loc[idfiltered_dataframe['Y'] == custom_date]  #Within group, filter rows where column Y has a custom date

    for row_1 in mindatefiltered_dataframe.index: #Iterate through mindatefiltered DataFrame and create list of each row value required

        row_list = [mindatefiltered_dataframe.at[row_1, 'X'], mindatefiltered_dataframe.at[row_1, 'Y'], mindatefiltered_dataframe.at[row_1, 'Z']]
        df_list.append(row_list) #Append to a master list

    for row_2 in customdatefiltered_dataframe.index: #Iterate through customdatefiltered DataFrame and create list of each row value required

        row_list = [customdatefiltered_dataframe.at[row_2, 'X'], customdatefiltered_dataframe.at[row_2, 'Y'], customdatefiltered_dataframe.at[row_2, 'Z']]
        df_list.append(row_list) #Append to a master list



print(pd.DataFrame(df_list)) #Create DataFrame out of the master list
```

I'm under the impression that there is some slick way, where you just do `df.groupby..` and get the expected output and I'm hoping someone could provide me with this code to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use -

```
date_fill = dt.datetime.strptime('2015-12-15', '%Y-%m-%d')
df['Y'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Y'], format='%Y-%m-%d')

df_g = df.loc[df.groupby(['X'])['Y'].idxmin()]
df2 = df[df['Y']==date_fill]
target_map = pd.Series(df2['Z'].tolist(),index=df2['X']).to_dict()
df_g.index = range(1, 2*len(df_g)+1, 2)
df_g = df_g.reindex(index=range(2*len(df_g)))
df_g['Y'] = df_g['Y'].fillna(date_fill)
df_g = df_g.bfill()
df_g.loc[df_g['Y']==date_fill, 'Z'] = df_g[df_g['Y']==date_fill]['X'].map(target_map)
df_g = df_g.bfill()
print(df_g)
```

**Output**

```
     X          Y     Z
0  1.0 2015-12-15  10.0
1  1.0 2015-12-15  10.0
2  2.0 2015-12-15  19.0
3  2.0 2015-12-11  22.0
4  3.0 2015-12-15  34.0
5  3.0 2015-12-12  31.0
```

**Explanation**

1. Put the desired custom date in `date_fill`
2. `df.groupby(['X'])['Y'].idxmin()` takes the rows by `min` of `Y`
3. `target_map` is a dict created to preserve `Z` values later
4. Next the `df_g` is expanded to have `na` values every alternate column
5. `df_g = df_g.bfill()` comes twice in case you enter a date in `date_fill` that isn't present in the `df`. In that case `target_map` won't populate and you will end up getting `na` values.

I am sure this can be optimized somewhat, but the thought process should help you proceed.

Answer (score 2):

IIUC

```
g1=df.groupby('X').Y.value_counts().count(level=1).eq(df.X.nunique()) # get group1 , all date should show in three groups , we using value_counts
df.Y=pd.to_datetime(df.Y) # change to date format in order to sort
g2=df.sort_values('Y').groupby('X').head(1) # get the min date row . 

pd.concat([df.loc[df.Y.isin(g1[g1].index)],g2]).sort_index() # combine all together 
Out[280]: 
   X          Y   Z
0  1 2015-12-15  10
0  1 2015-12-15  10
3  2 2015-12-15  19
4  2 2015-12-11  22
7  3 2015-12-12  31
8  3 2015-12-15  34
```

Comment: Thanks for taking this effort! Before I accept, if its not too much trouble, I would like to understand in which part of your answer are we getting the second row for each group? Because this is just a reproducible example, in my much larger example, I have to filter based on a custom date that doesn't have any pattern! In my reproducible example, it just turns out that in my example, for group `1`, `2015-12-15` is both the `mindate` as well as the `customdate`..